# VSTS UWP Build fails at tests

Tags: uwp, azure-devops

I am trying to make my build run my UWP unit tests.  It's failing because of this error:

```
vstest.console.exe 
2018-03-28T22:02:53.9581695Z "C:\A\Default\w\42\a\AppxPackages\EBMSMyTimeHelperTests_1.0.0.0_x86_Unit Tests_Test\EBMSMyTimeHelperTests_1.0.0.0_x86_Unit Tests.appx"
2018-03-28T22:02:53.9581797Z /logger:"trx"
2018-03-28T22:02:53.9581969Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2018-03-28T22:02:53.9582168Z Failed to launch testhost with error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.  C:\A\Default\w\42\a\AppxPackages\EBMSMyTimeHelperTests_1.0.0.0_x86_Unit Tests_Test\EBMSMyTimeHelperTests_1.0.0.0_x86_Unit Tests.appx ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Here is a screenshot of my test step:
[image]

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Using vstest.console.exe tool in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow` path instead.

You can specify vstest.console.exe path in Path to vstest.console.exe input box of **Visual Studio Test** task (Execution options > Choose Specific location)

Related issue: [vstest.console.exe crashing on UWP unit test project with “Data at the root level is invalid.”](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/724b10da-420f-4e99-8fc7-3279327dbd79/vstestconsoleexe-crashing-on-uwp-unit-test-project-with-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid?forum=vsunittest)

Comment: Tried that, and now I am getting the following:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Failed to launch testhost with error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: File 'C:\A\Default\w\42\a\AppxPackages\EBMSMyTimeHelperTests_1.0.0.0_x86_Unit Tests_Test\EBMSMyTimeHelperTests_1.0.0.0_x86_Unit Tests.appx' has an invalid extension, it must be '.appxrecipe'.

Comment: I ended up recreating my UWP test project and switching the test step to version 1.0 instead of 2.0 (without your solution).  That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very good solution, but it is a workaround...

I recreated my UWP test project (I don't know if this was necessary), recreated the test step, and switched the test step to version 1.* instead of 2.*.